# Controlling access to video stream

Tags: https, video-streaming, node.js, asp.net, django

I'm not sure if this is the right forum for this question, but here goes.

I have a video stream from a device on the local network that I would like to expose behind some kind of authentication. It's an android app that lets you stream video on the network. It has an authentication page, but it also gives you a url to the video stream.

Right now, I have assigned the device a static IP and set up port forwarding so I can view the stream from outside the network. I would like to play around with putting that video stream behind my own custom authentication. I guess I'm new to this stuff so I'm not really sure where to start. But here is what I'm looking for

- User hits an HTTPS page with login option.
- User logs in over HTTPS.
- Stream becomes available.
- User cannot just grab the stream URL and start playing the video without authentication.

I am familiar with making simple web server applications (Node, Django, ASP), but I'm trying to learn how I would go about setting up something like this.

I can make a HTTPS web page for starters, using maybe Google OAUTH (Node, express and Passport maybe).

But after that, I'm not sure what I should research to get something like this up an running.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: You can use a proxy to generate random url to serve the stream. The generated stream URL can be associated with a user's session so not to be share-able. Node.js/NPM `http-proxy` module might be helpful.

Comment: that's right. I guess the first step would be for me to set up a proxy.